# Show that $\left.\dfrac{d}{d s}\right|_{s=0}X_\eta (m)(f\circ \varphi_{\exp(s\xi )})=(X_\eta f)_{*,m}(X_\xi (m))$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, topological-vector-spaces

Let $G$ be a Lie group, $M$ be a manifold, $\varphi:G\times M \rightarrow M$ smooth action of $G$ over $M$ where $\varphi(g,m)=g\cdot m$. For each $\xi \in \mathfrak{g}=T_e G$ we difine the *fundamental vector field* $X_\xi \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$   as follows:
$$X_\xi (m)=\left.\dfrac{d}{d t}\right|_{t=0}\varphi(\exp(t\xi ),m )$$
where $\exp$ is exponential map. For each $g \in \mathfrak{g}=T_e G$ we difine $\varphi_g : M \rightarrow M$ where $\varphi_g (m)=\varphi(g,m)$, note that $\varphi_g $ is smooth.

Let $\xi,\eta \in \mathfrak{g}$. Show that 
$$\left.\dfrac{d}{d s}\right|_{s=0}X_\eta (m)(f\circ \varphi_{\exp(s\xi )})=(X_\eta f)_{*,m}(X_\xi (m))$$
where
\begin{array}{rcl}
X_k f:M &\rightarrow & \mathbb{R} \\
m &\rightarrow & X_k (m)(f)
\end{array}
for $k=\eta, \xi$ and $(X_\eta f)_{*,m}$ is differential at $m$ of $X_\eta f$.

Comment: I think this comes down tothe fact that the exponential function commutes with the derivations, but I need to think more about it.

Comment: Where I can find information about what you say?